# How is this code working for finding the number of divisors of a number?

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes, factors

http://www.spoj.com/problems/NDIV/

This is the problem statement. Since i'm new to programming, this particular problem ripped me off, I found this particular code on the internet which when I tried submitting got AC. I want to know how this code worked, as I have submitted it from online source which itself is bad idea for beginners.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int check[32000];
int prime[10000];
void shieve()
{
    for(int i=3;i<=180;i+=2)
    {
        if(!check[i])
        {
            for(int j=i*i;j<=32000;j+=i)
                check[j]=1;
        }
    } 
    prime[0] = 2;
    int j=1;
    for(int i=3;i<=32000;i+=2)
    {
        if(!check[i]){
            prime[j++]=i;
        }
    } 
}
int main()
{ 
    shieve();
    int a,b,n,temp,total=1,res=0;
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&n);
    int count=0,i,j,k;
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        temp=i;
        total=1;
        k=0;
        for(j=prime[k];j*j<=temp;j=prime[++k])
        {
            count=0;
            while(temp%j==0)
            {
                count++;
                temp/=j;
            }
            total *=count+1;
        }
        if(temp!=1)
            total*=2;
        if(total==n)
            res++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",res);
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like the code works on the sieve of eratosthenes, but a few things i'm unable to understand.

1. Why the limit of array "check" is 32000?
2. Again why the limit for array prime is 10000?
3. Inside main, whatever is happening inside the for loop of j.

Too many confusions regarding this approach, can someone explain the whole algorithm how it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The hard limit on the arrays is set probably because the problem demands so? If not then just bad code.
2. Inside the inner loop, you are calculating the largest power of a prime that divides the number. Why? See point 3.
3. The number of factors of a number n can be calculated as follows:

   Let n  = (p1)^(n1) * (p2)^(n2) ... where p1, p2 are primes and n1, n2 ... are their exponents. Then the number of factors of n = (n1 + 1)*(n2 + 1)...

   Hence the line `total *= count + 1` which is basically `total = total * (count + 1)` (where `count` is the largest exponent of the prime number that divides the original number) calculates the number of prime factors of the number.

And yes, the code implements sieve of Eratosthenes for storing primes in a table.

(*Edit* Just saw the problem - you need at least 10^4 `boolean` values to store the primes (you don't actually need to store the values, just a flag indicating whether the values are prime or not). The condition given is `0 <= b - a <= 10^4` , So start your loop from `a` to `b` and check for the `bool` values stored in the array to know if they are prime or not.)